# Android Studio Binding Error Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, xml, firebase

[Heres the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be2d3.png)

I want to display the text and images from firestore.

or are there other ways how to display data from firestore database to recyclerview.

**AllProducts.java**

```
public class AllProducts extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityAllProductsBinding binding;
    MyProductsAdapter myProductsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityAllProductsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        myProductsAdapter=new MyProductsAdapter(this);
        binding.productsRecycler.setAdapter(myProductsAdapter);

        loadProduct();
    }
    private void loadProduct(){
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("PRODUCTS")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        List<DocumentSnapshot> dsList=queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot ds:dsList){
                            Product product=ds.toObject(Product.class);
                            myProductsAdapter.add(product);
                        }

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the layout file that is inflated.

Comment: Please also share the adapter file.